# $f \in L^1 ((0,1))$, decreasing on $(0,1)$ implies $x f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f\in L^1((0,1),dm)$. Suppose $f$ is also a decreasing function on $(0,1)$. Prove that

$$\lim _\limits{x \to 0} xf(x) = 0.$$

**My attempt at a solution**

We may assume without loss of generality that $f$ is positive, and unbounded near zero; thus we can write

$$\infty >\int_0^1 f\,dm=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac 1n}f\,dm.$$

Then

$$ \int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac 1n}f\,dm \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as}\quad n\rightarrow \infty. $$

Also since $f$ is decreasing, we have

$$f \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left( \frac 1n - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) \leq \int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac 1n}f\,dm \leq f \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\left( \frac 1n - \frac{1}{n+1}\right).$$

I want to say

$$ \lim _\limits{x \to 0} xf(x) = \lim _\limits{n \to \infty} \frac 1n f \left( \frac 1n \right) = 0,$$

But that's not exactly what I have in my inequalities.

**Added** as pointed out by @Hetebrij below,

> Note that by showing $\lim _\limits{n \to \infty} \frac1n f\left( \frac 1n  \right) =0$ you have not shown $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}xf(x)=0$ unless you know
>   (1) the limit exist or (2) $xf(x)$ is decreasing or increasing.

Any hints or suggestions? Would contradiction be better suited for this problem?

**UPDATE** Another attempt:

Take any $n>1$. Then

$$\frac {1}{2n}f \left(\frac 1n\right) = \left(\frac 1n-\frac {1}{2n}\right)f \left(\frac 1n\right) \leq \int_{[0,1]}f(x)\chi_{\left[\frac{1}{2n},\frac 1n\right]}(x)dx.$$

Now the sequence of functions

$$f(x)\chi_{\left[\frac{1}{2n},\frac 1n\right]}(x)$$ is dominated by the integrable function $f$, and converges to $\infty\cdot \chi_{\{0\}}$. Thus by the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have

$$\int_{[0,1]}f(x)\chi_{\left[\frac{1}{2n},\frac 1n\right]}(x)dx \rightarrow 0.$$

Comment: Isn't $L^1$ the space of Lebesgue integrable functions? If it is, could you justify why you can use the Riemann integral in your first equation (the one with the $\infty$ on the left hand side)?

Comment: +1 by the way, for posting your solution, regardless of whether it's correct or not.

Comment: Not that by showing $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} f \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) = 0$ you have not shown $\lim_{x \to 0 } x f(x) =0$ unless you know 1) the limit exist or 2) $xf(x)$ is decreasing or increasing.

Comment: @Hetebrij I do see your point

Comment: @RudytheReindeer Thanks! Yes $dm$ here stands for Lebesgue measure.     I think I see your point.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't trying to make a point -- I was merely asking a question (to which I don't know the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume first that $f\geq 0$ (which you did without much justification). Then $f (x)\geq f (x_0) $ for $x\leq x_0$ and thus
$$
\int_0^{x_0} f (x)\,dx \geq \int_0^{x_0} f (x_0)\,dx = x_0 f (x_0) \geq 0.
$$
But (e.g. using dominated convergence), we easily see that the left-hand side of the estimate converges to $0$. This yields the claim.

Actually, the proof above just used that for $x_0>0$ small enough, we have $f (x_0)\geq 0$.

Thus, the remaining case is that there are arbitrarily small $x_0>0$ with $f (x_0)<0$. By monotonicity, this yields $f (x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in (0,1) $. Hence,
$$
0 \geq x \cdot f (x) \geq x \cdot f (1/2) \to 0
$$
as $x \to 0$. Thus, the claim also holds in this case.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help!